# Is it appropriate to edit your code into someone else's abandoned question that you bounty?

Tags: discussion, edits, bounty

I recently put a bounty on a 3-year-old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610606/chartjs-annotations-working-but-causing-console-error-in-angular-5) that had no answer. (I have the exact same issue). It was the OP's only question, and their profile indicates that they have not signed in in a long time.

A commenter asked for code from the OP; I assumed that the OP would not sign in to see the comment before the bounty expired (and may not even have access to the relevant code anymore anyway) and edited my code in to the question with a note that it wasn't the OP's code, but that it reproduces the specified problem.

Was it appropriate for me to do that (given that it technically conflicted with the OP's intent, but the OP isn't really around to edit anymore)?

Comment: If you had to add the MCVE anyway, why not just create a new question instead?

Comment: Yeah... I was in process of typing up an answer in support, because I can see cases where this could be defensible (questions are primarily for the knowledge base first, and OP second, afterall), but I don't think _this_ case is a great application of it. Your snippet belongs as a comment under the bountied question, or in a new question altogether (which is find since this one has no answers), _especially_ since your added example uses Angular 8, when the question is about Angular _5_.

Comment: Also related: [Is it appropriate to add a Minimal, Reproducible example as an edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413423)

Comment: If you can write a better question and it gets answered, we'll close the old question as a duplicate.

Comment: I must say... you handled the edit quite well, I don't think it conflicts with anything at all. Too bad a little fluff text was needed to make it clear but you do what you have to do.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think a better option in this case would have been to ask a new question, include your MCVE in that new question, and then add a bounty to the new question if it doesn't get an answer after a few days.

Your new question would not be closed as a duplicate of the old one, because a question must have an accepted and/or upvoted answer to be a dupe target. On the other hand, if your new question did receive an answer, then the *old* question could then potentially be closed as a duplicate of it.

This would be better because if a question lacks a MCVE, then it generally is not clear and unambiguous enough to know what the OP's intent was exactly. As you know, edits aren't supposed to conflict with the original author's intent; but if the author's intent cannot be determined unambiguously then you cannot know whether or not a non-trivial edit would conflict with it. See [this other meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413423/is-it-appropriate-to-add-a-minimal-reproducible-example-as-an-edit) for further discussion.

Comment: but they already put a bounty on the question

Comment: "if the author's intent cannot be determined unambiguously..." Basically what is left is to determine if the author's intent can be determined unambiguously for this question. Maybe this could be added to the answer.

Comment: @Juraj  Note that this answer says "would have been".  The presumption is that the question is about the general practice, not this specific case, as the question asks "is it appropriate" not "what should I do now?"  Both of the current answers are essentially implying that it was inappropriate to bounty a question without an MCVE.  The later inappropriate edit is only a symptom of that.  And while it sucks to waste a bounty, it's not exactly the end of the world.  There is nothing stopping the OP from placing bounties on both questions (except potentially not enough reputation).

Answer (score 34):

No - don't make edits that conflict with the OP's intent.

If you have a separate question with specific code, you should create a separate question instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how to feel about this as a whole, but I do think that there's an argument to be made that adding code that reproduces the problem asked about by the OP doesn't _necessarily_ violate the OP's intent. Definitely would be a case by case thing, but I think this would be especially true if the question is about the problem generically and isn't a debug question.

Comment: @zcoop98 I agree it doesn't necessarily conflict with their intent, but at the same time without knowing OPs code it could for all we know have a different cause, just be totally unhelpful to them, or anything else. While that may not matter here with the age of the question and unavailable OP, the correct action would still be for EJoshuaS to post their own question and then, when answered, for this one [being discussed] to be closed as a dupe of the newer one.

Comment: but they already put a bounty on the question

Comment: @Juraj  The solution to that (in this case) would be to link to the new question from the old question, referring the person requesting the MCVE to the new question.

Comment: @Juraj:  I don't see how that's relevant here

Comment: maybe just I would expect answers to address it, because the Help Center has "If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more answers". and then it ends like this.

Comment: @Juraj:  In general, sure, but in this specific case (or this specific class of cases), it's more than preferable to ask your own question and bounty *that* one if you have to, especially if the question you bountied lacks context or code and is more susceptible to being closed for that reason.

Comment: yes that is what I miss in the answer

Answer (score 0):

The OP posted the question under a [Creative Commons licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license), which allows anyone to edit the question. If the edit is outright spam or slander, it can be reverted. In this case, the OP provided an error, but not a minimal reproducible example to reproduce the error. You provided the example in an attempt to improve the abandoned question.

I don't see any reason that you cannot or should not provide  a minimal reproducible example, which improves the post. I don't see any conflict with the author's intent either. The post is there for the benefit of the community, not just for the OP. Unless the edit clearly breaks any accepted community norms, the edit is acceptable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the creative commons license - that allows you to make derivative works, the CC license by itself doesn't grant permission to modify the original. So this is a red herring.

Comment: @kaya3 It's not modifying the original. It's a derivative of the original. The last derivative or revision is the one that's displayed. The original is preserved as the first revision.

Comment: It would make more sense to consider the archived version as a copy of the original, since it appears at a different URL and is presented differently. My point is that we can take it as given that it is *legal* to edit someone else's question on Stack Overflow - the legality of doing so is not at issue - but the CC license doesn't make it legal to do so, Stack Overflow's terms of service do. Either way, this is not relevant to the question or your answer, because we're not discussing whether the edit in question was legal, we're discussing whether it was *good*.

Comment: @kaya3 Content matters.Presentation is secondary. The original is preserved. The point of bringing up the licence is simple: The post's original revision belongs to the author. The rest doesn't.  The post  currently displayed/the current revision is a community effort. Any member of a community can attempt to improve the post acceptable within the community norms. The edit by OP doesn't deviate from community norms. The original author is not the owner of the current revision, but only the original revision. Bringing up the CC licence and ownership helps to see clearly whether the edit is good

Comment: *"The edit by OP doesn't deviate from community norms."* What's at issue in this meta Q&A is *whether* it deviates from community norms, and the CC license is not evidence either way. If you want to know what the community norms are, instead of reading the CC license it would make more sense to read what the community has written about its own norms, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327373/12299000) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413423/12299000).

Comment: @kaya3 Understanding that this post belongs to the community and not just the author is a crucial factor in deciding that this edit is acceptable. What makes that understanding clear is the CC licence. I could make the case in those questions too. But this caught my eye and therefore I answered. I disagree that the licence plays no part in this decision. I consider the licence foundation for my stance.

Comment: Releasing something under a CC license does not mean that thing belongs to the community, it means the author has granted the community permission to use it in certain ways. Editing the original posting to replace it with a different version is not one of the permissions granted by the CC license; the license only permits you to create a different version of their post, it doesn't give you permission to put your different version of their post in a particular place. It is Stack Overflow's terms of service which permit you to do that.

Comment: @kaya3 As I already said, The original is preserved. Only the derivative works are assumed superior by stackoverflow and the recent derivative work is displayed. Nothing  is removed.

Comment: The new edited version goes in the *place* where the original version of it used to be, and that original version is now in a different *place*. If you don't understand that to be *replacing* then I don't know what to tell you. If you *replace* the curtains in your house, everyone understands that the old curtains still exist.

Comment: @kaya3 I agree. SO/Community decides what version is superior and needs to put in front. That has nothing to do with the ability to do put up a version for a community to decide. OP asks "Is it appropriate?" The license grants that authority is a important factor. The post doesn't belong to the OP only is a important factor.  Except the first version, the rest belongs to the community is a important factor.

Answer (score -4):

It's a no-win situation.

Take your pick:

1. Ask a new question and get it rejected as a duplicate (apparently can't happen but I'm not confident question wouldn't be down-voted out of existence by some users anyway)
2. Edit original question, add a bounty and be voted down

To paraphrase the rules, questions are intended to be of interest to the community; if they meet your need that's a bonus. I can't see that's changed by offering a bounty.

Comment: If the original question has no answers, it is not eligible as a duplicate.

Comment: Very simple to say you found the other question but it had no answers and no mcve as you write the new question